# Rails Active Record specify where on relational model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

If I have this relationship:

`Foo has_many :bars`

`Bar belongs_to :foo`

I want to specify a scope in the `Foo` model since there are a few fields in that I want to filter by (i.e. `where("code='AV1' OR code='AH5'"`)

The `bars` have foreign keys for the `Foo` in it. How do I specify the `bars` that fit the above mentioned filter? Something like `Bar.foo.customScope` and let's say I want to filter for something in `Bar` as well ?

`Bar.where(".....").foo.customScope`?

EDIT

yes, code is a field in the foo table

I have a few hundred k entries in the `bars` table. Each of them has a foreign key to the `foos` Table (model `Foo`). I want to get a list of all `bars` that have a certain `code` from the `foos` table. E.g.

```
foos:
id, code
1,okay
2,not okay
3,somewhat okay

bars:
id,foo_id,otherstuff
1,1,blah
2,1,blob
3,2,hello
4,3,hurray
```

if my Foo model looks like this:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :bars

   def self.goodCodes
     where("code='okay' or code='somewhat okay')
   end

end
```

and my Bar model looks like this:

```
class Bar < ActiveRcord::Base
  belongs_to :foo
end
```

I want to call something get all the `Bar` items that fit a condition as well as that have `foos` that satisfy the `goodCodes` condition. I thought it would go something like this: `Bar.where(....).foo.goodCodes` or alternatively,

```
Bar.where(...).each do |row|
  if row.foo.goodCodes
    ##do something
  end
end
```

Comment: So, have you tried simply creating the scope in Foo class? That did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There must be some confusion. Since `Bar` belongs to 1 and only 1 `foo`, running `@bar.foo` will only ever return 1 result: the `foo` you assigned to `@bar`. Scopes are for returning multiple records.

If you had the scope you mentioned in the `Foo` model:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :customScope, -> { where("code='AV1' OR code='AH5'") }
end
```

Then the `customScope` Scope is a class method on the `Foo` class:

```
Foo.customScope # e.g. => [#<Foo code='AV1'], ...]
```

But if the scope is on the `Bar` class:

```
class Bar < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :customScope, -> { where("code='AV1' OR code='AH5'") }
end
```

Then you call `Bar.customScope` and return all the `bars` that match that condition. You can also call it to get a subset of `Foo`'s `bars`:

```
foo = Foo.new
foo.bars << Bar.new(code: 'AV1')
foo.bars << Bar.new(code: 'XXX')

foo.bars # => [#<Bar code: 'AV1'>, #<Bar code: 'XXX'>]
foo.bars.customScope # => [#<Bar code: 'AV1'>]
```

To clear up any confusion when you said:

> I want to specify a scope in the Foo model since there are a few
>   fields in that I want to filter by (i.e. where("code='AV1' OR
>   code='AH5'")

I take it that `code` is a field in `Foo`. But then you said:

> How do I specify the bars that fit the above mentioned filter?

Well, you can't. If the `code` field is in the `Foo` table then that filter can only be for the `Foo` model. You can't filter `Bar`s by the fields in a different database table. You can however, get all the `Foo`s that match the filter, or scope, `Foo.customScope` and then get all those `foo`s `bar`s:

```
Foo.customScope.flat_map &:bars
```

Further, there's no such method `Bar.foo`. `Bar` is a class, only instances of `Bar` will respond to `foo`:

```
Bar.foo # NoMethodError
bar = Bar.new
bar.foo = Foo.new
bar.foo # the new foo
```

**Update:**

This won't work:

```
row.foo.goodCodes
```

Because `goodCodes` is a class method on Foo, not on instances such as `row.foo`. Like I said above, you need to do this:

```
Foo.customScope.flat_map &:bars
```

To get all the `bar`s whose `foo`s match the condition.

The reason is that when you get an instance of `Bar` such as in:

```
Bar.where(...).each do |row|
  if row.foo.goodCodes
    ##do something
  end
end
```

`row` is now an *instance* of Bar. `row.foo` will return an *instance* of `foo`. **You can't call scopes or class methods on *instances***. This won't work: `row.foo.goodCodes`, because you defined `goodCodes` as a class method of Foo. You can, as previously mentioned, call:

```
foos_with_good_codes = Foo.goodCodes
bars_with_foos_that_have_good_codes = foos_with_good_codes.flat_map &:bars
```

Hope that clears it up a bit.

Comment: I edited my question, This should make my requirement more apperent.

Comment: thanks for clearing that up. I am new to AR but this makes a lot of sense

Comment: In fact, you CAN achieve what the OP wants through the 'merge' method. Check out my response, Diego.